# List inside a list BeautifulSoup unclosed <li> extraction issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

SO i am having issue with extracting values from a security advisory, a section is as below

```
<ul>
  <li>
   ABC
   <ul>
    <li>
     XYZ
    </li>
    <li>
     PQR
    </li>
```

when i do a find_all on li and iterate and print it i get

```
ABCXYZPQR
XYZ
PQR
```

instead of what i want to get is

```
ABC
XYZ
PQR
```

i understand this is happening because the li for ABC is not closed so it is reading the whole sublist

what i am unble to figure out is how do i extract just ABC, there is not way to split it also post converting it to string because there is no common thing to split it on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
import bs4
def get_li(d):
   if d.name == 'li':
     yield ''.join(str(i).strip() for i in d.contents if isinstance(i, bs4.NavigableString))
   for i in d.contents:
      if not isinstance(i, bs4.NavigableString):
         yield from get_li(i)

source = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(list(get_li(source)))
```

Output:

```
['ABC', 'XYZ', 'PQR']
```

Comment: worked brilliantly, if you can add some explanation into your answer, i will mark it.